# How to efficiently restore an stl container to old values

Tags: c++, performance, stl

I have a large class representing a graph. This class containing several containers (vector and set) of complex types.
During search I need to modify the graph to avoid loops in the results.
Since I have to run many searches I need to restore the class to its originial state very often.

Currently I am simply assigning the saved continers to the modified ones:

```
 void Graph::restore(){
   mEdges=mSafeEdges; //std::vector<Edge> Edge has no heap based data
   mNodes=mSafeNodes; //std::vector<GraphNode> A Graph Node contains std::set<int>
 }
```

As I said, Edges and nodes are complex, with each node conaining e.g. a set.
Each pair of containers has equal size. Profiling my code showed that the simple restore function is the major bottleneck of the programme, taking approx 6ms at each run. The edge vector takes 1.5 ms to copy and the nodes 4.5. Is there a better, faster way to copy containers of complex types or at least to copy the Edge Vector ?

Comment: If you only make a few modifications, you could just make a list of those and restore by reverting the changes.

Comment: Or, don't mutate the data; store your state somewhere else.

Comment: @smocking Unfortunately there are quite many modifications

Comment: @JamesMcNellis This could be difficult but might be an option none the less. I'm searching for closed polygons and the only alternative would be to store the already visited lines and compare against those at every line comparison. As there are a lot of comparisons this will turn out quite expensive ...

Comment: I'd start with a `std::set<edge> visited_edges;` (or `std::set<edge*>`, or a `std::unordered_set`).  Then the test becomes `if (!visited_edges.insert(e).second) { /* edge was already visited */ }`.  If that turns out to be too slow, you could investigate other options.  Using external storage is non-invasive, so it should be easy to try out and profile.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: True I should at least try it. Should not take too long to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you only modify some of the objects on each search then you could see whether copy-on-write helps.

```
template<typename T>
class Cow {
  std::shared_ptr<T> owned;
  const Node* non_owned;
public:
  explicit Cow(const T& n) : non_owned(n) { }
  const T& get() const { return *non_owned; }
  T& copy() {
    if (!owned) {
      owned = std::make_shared<T>(*non_owned);
      non_owned = owned.get();
    }
    return *owned;
  }
};
```

Then replace `mEdges` and `mNodes` with containers of `Cow<Edge>` and `Cow<GraphNode>` (or only do it for nodes, since that's the more expensive type to copy).

You'd have to modify the search logic to work with the wrapper type (or give it a conversion operator to `const T&`) and then explicitly add a call to `copy()` when you want a modifiable object, but you would avoid making copies of objects unless necessary.

Comment: I think I was not clear enough in my question : I need the modification as a tag so copying instead of modifying would not help

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, sorry. There is no way to make a faster copy, if there was then the containers would use it already! So un-ask the question and remove the need for all the copying by not mutating the data or only copying as much as necessary.